# Sum values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to sum up values in mysql as in excel? I´m currently trying query below but it sums up the values on another rows. I need something that wil be working like sum function in excel and if I add some values into the table, the values will summed in the column (spolu) automatically.

```
INSERT INTO test (spolu)
SELECT SUM(hodnota1+hodnota2)
FROM test
GROUP BY id
```

This query do this:

[image: This query do this:]

but i need this:

[image]

Comment: Redundancy generally is not a good idea. Why don't select the sum when it need?

Comment: you actualy want to update a column in that case:`UPDATE test SET spolu = hodnota1 + hodnota2 ` should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simple `+`:

```
SELECT id, hodnota1, hodnota2, hodnota1 +  hodnota2 AS spolu
FROM test;
```

For automatic calculating you need to use trigger or generated column.

**[`Generated columns 5.7+`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)**

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMNET,
  hodnota1 INT,
  hodnota2 INT,
  spolu INT AS (hodnota1 + hodnota2)
);
```

Another way is to create view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_test
AS
SELECT id, hodnota1, hodnota2, hodnota1 +  hodnota2 AS spolu
FROM test;
```

Comment: Thank you sir this works. Could please little bit more explain trigger or computed column?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you need it as a table, you could create a view with this output.

```
SELECT id, hodnota1, hodnota2, 
SUM(hodnota1, hodnota2) AS spolu
FROM test;
GROUP BY id
```